# Jquery Quick Hack for soundcloud

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundcloud, code-snippets

I am a bit of a crate digger and soundcloud had been a great tool to find some new cool tracks. 
And the best way to find ID is to look in the comments, but there is a problem, they all have a timestamp, but no way to sort them with this timestamp.

Is there a quick way to do that with jquery directly in chrome js console ?

In comment pages the stucture of each comment is

```
<li class="commentsList__item">
  <div class="commentItem sc-media large">
    <a class="sc-media-image commentItem__avatar" href="/username">
        <img src="[...]" width="40" height="40" alt="Users’s avatar">
    </a>
    <div class="commentItem__content sc-media-content">
      <span class="commentItem__createdAt sc-text-light">
        <time class="relativeTime" title="Posted on 9 April 2014 11:15" datetime="2014-04-09T09:15:44.000Z">
          <span class="sc-visuallyhidden">Posted 21 mins ago</span>
          <span aria-hidden="true">21 mins</span>
        </time>
      </span>
      <div class="commentItem__controls"> <a href="/platform/[nameofthetrack]/comments/[commentID]" class="sc-button sc-button-reply sc-button-medium commentItem__replyButton" title="Open this comment">Reply</a> 
      </div>
      <div class="commentItem__body sc-font-light"> <a href="/[username]" title="Visit [Username]’s profile" class="commentItem__username sc-link-dark">[Username]</a> 
        <span>[Comment]</span>
        <span class="sc-text-light commentItem__timestamp">at 10.08</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

The data i want to target for sorting is :

```
<span class="sc-text-light commentItem__timestamp">at 10.08</span>
```

With this little js snippet i would be able to rapidly find trackrequest and trackid in a song. 
Do you see what i mean?

Comment: "10.08" is not a timestamp... So a comment begins with a `<div class="commentItem"...`, right ?

Comment: "9 April 2014 11:15" is a better way to get a real timestamp

Comment: I think you have misinterpreted my question. My goal is not to sort the comments by their time of posting but by their position in the song. This is why the data i need to taget is the one in the `.sc-text-light.commentItem__timestamp` div.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like that :

```
var comments = [];
// iterate on every comment item
$(".commentItem").each(function() {
    // get the time under the YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS format
    var datestr = $(this).find(".commentItem__timestamp").text();
    var time = parseInt(datestr.replace("at ","").replace(".",""));
    // key is the corresponding integer (10.08 => 1008)
    comments[time] = $(this);
});

var keys = Object.keys(comments);
keys.sort();

var result = [];

len = keys.length;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    result.push(comments[keys[i]]);
}

// now you have a sorted array (from the oldest to the most recent)
// you can use the reverse method to reverse the sorting.
```

Comment: Yes this would work but the time of posting is not what i am interested on. I want to targer the timing in the song where the comment is posted on. So the data to target is the one in the `.sc-text-light.commentItem__timestamp` div. 

A bit of parsing is needed to remove the `at ` but it can be done easyly with something like `.replace('at ','')`

Comment: You just have to delete any non numeric character and cast it as an integer (string)"at 10.08" become (int)1008 => easy sorting.

Comment: I've modified my answer, can you try and tell me if it works ? =)

Comment: Thanks. I have something but it's strange. 
1 : my JS console dont like `var comments[];` but it prefers `var comments = [];` and `ParseInt()` -> `parseInt()`.
2 : when i enter that in the console i get a stange output : an array with all the div targeted but in the exact order (chronologically in fact (time of posting)) that they are displayed in the page. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0oz4uizkopx1os3/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202014-04-15%2016.03.09.jpg

I would like to sort with this parameter (see screenshot) : 
http://note.io/1m59ozk

Comment: got a "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: it seems to come from the `keys.sort();`line

Comment: Of course, I made a mistake, Object.Keys returns the set of keys. I edited my post